How to migrate home assistant data to a new device?
I tested Home Assistant OS on my Raspberry Pi 3 for a while and now I'd like to migrate to a Pi 5 running Raspberry Pi OS and home assistant via docker instead. I downloaded a backup from the Pi 3 and extracted the contents of homeassistant.tar.gzto the container's config path, but still get greeted by the onboarding site and have none of the old data taken over. How can I properly migrate my installation?
